# Vimeo player custom controls

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I´m using froogaloop to work with Vimeo in order to use it in my sites. My problem here is that I´d like to customize the player as you can see here in the "Customize to your taste" part -> http://vimeo.com/player

The last point is a simplified control interface that I would like to use, but I´m not capable to do it. These are the parameters that we seem to be able to tweak -> http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding#universal-parameters

Any idea about how to work with these features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plus and PRO members can choose to customize their embeds (https://vimeo.com/s/tce). Those options are not available as embed code parameters.